# How to use binary search in order to find the first element in an array that has certain weight (another element in a different array)?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

All the methods here are correct, but my problem is that i have to find a part in the parts array that has a certain weight. So After i do the getweight method I think i have to call that. But the last part of the code is what i have a problem with. It starts with the line  public Part getPartWithWeight (int weight){

```
class Robot {
             Part[] parts;
                 public Robot () {// assume these are right}
                 }
                 public void addPart(Part p) { // assume these are right}
                 }

             class Part {
             // Class details not shown
                 public double getWeight() {//... }
                 }
                 public int getPartnum() {//...}
                 }
                 public String getMaterial() {//...}     
                 }

             public Part getPartWithWeight (int weight){
             for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i ++){
                 if (parts[i].weight == weight) {
                     return parts[i];
                 }
                 }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the setup.  What are the weights?  What are the arrays?  How are they sorted?

Comment: the array is already sorted and the weight is already passed in by doing the getweight method. SO you just need to call it. Also the array is the parts array in the start of the code.

Comment: If the `parts` array is not sorted by weight, then a binary search is inappropriate.  Binary searches work only on sorted data.

Comment: I know the array is already sorted

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's the "works-out-of-the-box" version.

**Step 1** Write a comparator.

```
class PartComparator implements java.util.Comparator<Part> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Part part1, Part part2) {
        return part1.weight - part2.weight;
    }
    public final static PartComparator instance = new PartComparator();
}
```

The comparator class should be static if you declare it inside Part (which is what I would suggest).

**Step 2** Use the comparator

```
public Part getPartWithWeight (int weight){
    Part pivot = new Part();
    pivot.weight = weight;
    int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(parts, pivot, PartComparator.instance);
    return parts[idx];
}
```

Comment: This is great but not really what im looking for this is way more complex and detailed then i need it to be. I just need to binary search and search for the first element that has the int weight from the getweight method.

Comment: Also the array is already made all the other methods do their job i just need to call them and find the element with the same weight as the weight from the getweight method.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (parts[i].weight == weight)
```

should say

```
if (parts[i].getWeight() == weight)
```

You should use **getWeight()** because that's the method defined in the Parts class.
Also if you're problem is getting the parts array from the robot class and using it in the part class then you should just pass it as a parameter.

```
public Part getPartWithWeight (int weight, Part[] parts){
  for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i ++){
    if (parts[i].getWeight() == weight) {
      return parts[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Then when you call the method getPartWithWeight() make sure you put the array in there too.

EDIT: Also per Ray Cheng's comment, the weight you're looking for is supposed to be an int but your getWeight() method returns a double.... so either your getWeight() should return an in or you should typecast it as an int before making the comparison. Be aware that if you typecast it as an int you will lose some precision. It would be better to fix your getWeight() so it returns a double like you need it to.

Comment: The getWeight() method returns a double but the weight argument is an int.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a binary search, you first need to cut the array in half and then decide which half you want to begin the search. Then you cut the halved array in half again and repeat...

Unless you want to implement your own, but looks like there is a built-in one you can call.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Arrays.html